# angular 2 ngfor li containing string of html

Tags: angular, hyperlink, html-lists, ngfor

I have a tabs bar that is fine when coded as HTML, but fails when I try to generate the

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let nxt of all">
    {{nxt}}
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link  tabLink active" data-toggle="tab" >Shipment <span class="fa fa-close"></span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The component has:

```
this.all = new Array();
let x = '<a class="nav-link  tabLink active" data-toggle="tab" >Shipment <span class="fa fa-close"></span></a>';
this.all.push(x);
```

the results: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti3tw.jpg)

so how do I convert the string to an html object in the ngFor loop
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `outerHTML` property binding like.

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let nxt of all">
  <i [outerHTML]="nxt"></i>
</li>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/KYIIHkG1rdqTzJTouYEt?p=preview)**

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.   Thanks.